# ¿Cuál es la razón por la que la palabra inmunidad se adaptó con "n" y no con "m" al Español?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, prefijos, latinismo

Escribiendo en Inglés me dí cuenta que inmunidad en ese idioma se escribe con "m", *Immunity*. Como muchas palabras del Español viene del Inglés decidí buscar su Etimología y parece provenir del Latín "Immunis", también con m. Pero en Español ya sea la hayamos adaptado del Latín o del Inglés, la escribimos con "n", Inmunidad. ¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Tiene que ver con alguna regla ortográfica del Español, o hay algun otro motivo, o es desconocido?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*inmunidad* is a Latin loanword and has been reanalysed in terms of its prefixes:

- in- +‎ mūnus +‎ -is > immunis `lat` > inmune `esp`

The prefix [*in-*](https://dle.rae.es/in-) is rendered:

- in- (generalmente)
- im- (ante *b* o *p*)
- i- (ante *l* o *r*)

While it would be equally valid to include spelling /m/ as "m" before "m" or "v", the [orthographic standard](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/orthogra.htm) is to only spell it as such before "p" or "b" (despite "b" and "v" representing the same sound). [Other examples](https://dle.rae.es/inm?m=31) include:

- *inmaculada, inmadurez, inmanencia, inmaterial, inmediatamente, inmemorial, inmersión, inmigración* etc